# How to permanently close a port?

Tags: networking, security, services, tcp-ip

I tried first adding a firewall rule

```
sudo ufw deny 22

$ sudo ufw status
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         DENY        Anywhere 
22 (v6)                    DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

but it didn't worked so I tried to stop the services corresponding to it

```
  sudo systemctl stop ssh
```

it works temporarily and when we reboot the system the same port will be open again. How to permanently close a port?

Comment: How did the firewall rule not work? Is it actually enabled (`sudo ufw enable`, check with `sudo ufw status verbose`)? Note that the firewall only blocks access from outside, not localhost. To disable the ssh server service permanently, try `sudo systemctl disable ssh`.

Comment: That firewall status looks like it should work and deny all traffic in port 22. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: I tried to login ssh as a localhost `ssh username@127.0.0.1` and it was successful. `sudo systemctl disable ssh` worked, can you write this as an answer so it will be helpful to some one else.

Comment: @Eka no wonder you thought it not worked, 127.0.0.1 is not run through the firewall at all

Comment: @Videonauth I didn't know that, learned something new today.

Comment: @Eka The solution you're asking for and the question you're asking is not the same thing.  Closing a port is not the same as disabling ssh.  Rather than Byte Commander's solution (which is correct), why not uninstall the openssh-server package?  Perhaps someone else can clarify what you're seeing but I *guess* ssh to the localhost might not be using port 22?  Indeed, what you did does close the port.  So I don't think that's wrong.

Comment: @Eka I can also add that ssh doesn't have to use port 22.  You can change the port the ssh server uses in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Comment: @eka are you on Desktop or Server? SSH is important for both systems. As Ray says, change the ssh port in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. if you are on a server install firewall + Fail2ban ; on desktop install GUFW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you add a firewall rule to deny all traffic on a specific port number like 22 in the `ufw` firewall using:

```
sudo ufw deny 22
```

Note that `ufw` must be enabled so that this rule can have effect, of course:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Check the status, defaults and a list of all rules with:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

You can also install the firewall GUI `gufw` to manage these rules and defaults, if you prefer that over the command line.

This way makes the port only inaccessible over the network, from *outside your computer*. You can still access the port on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, as local traffic is not filtered by the firewall. The service listening on this port can also still be running and is not affected by any firewall rules.

---

If you want to prevent a systemd service from starting automatically at boot, you can disable it. To disable e.g. the ssh server, use:

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh
```

This command just disables the autostart of a service. It can still be started automatically if another service or target requires it, or you can also still start it manually. It does not affect the ports used by the service, just stops the service from running and listening on that port, but as soon as it gets started, it will listen again.

---

If you generally don't want to have an ssh server running on your machine, you can just completely uninstall the package:

```
sudo apt remove openssh-server
```

This uninstalls (and stops, of course) the ssh server application, but does not affect any ports and firewall rules.